# Flow formula not computing correctly (is simple math)

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I have a simple math formula in my flow, the formula field is adjustedCost the body of the formula is...

```
{!$Record.Maximum_Bill_Rate__c} - {!profitDiscount} - {!profitDelta}
```

The data passed into the formula is:
Maximum_Bill_Rate__c = 70
profitDiscount = .427
profitDelta = 15.67

Expected result: 53.90
Actual result: 86.24

Don't know why this is happening, seems like it should simply work.

Update: I have added a screen shot of the flow decision I added to show what the values are the formula is using...
[image]

Comment: Are those values what's displayed in the debug section of the flow, or just what you'd expect them to be?

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the currently activated version of the flow?

Comment: Seems like `profitDiscount` and `profitDelta` may be negative.

Comment: Those numbers are displayed in the debug view of the flow.

Comment: see updated screen shot, is profitDelta negative since it has double parenths?

Comment: yep it is, thanks @AdrianLarson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have negative values, so when you subtract them, it is effectively a sum of the absolute values.